# SSH to docker bridged instance

Tags: jenkins, docker, ssh, connection-reset

I'm trying to run some Docker instances to allow Jenkins to perform some jobs on them.

I followed this tutorial (http://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/) to achieve it. It's currently creating some new docker instances, but it does not connect to them.

All of these new docker instances must have direct access to physical network, so they have to be built with "-net=bridge". Each port 22 of each docker container is being binded to a free host port.

So, the thing is that I cannot reach any docker instance through SSH access.
Moreover, If I get into one of these docker instances, i'm not able to do ssh to localhost getting the next:

```
[jenkins@d4084633f2bc ~]$ ssh localhost -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/jenkins/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

How can I solve this? Does anybody know it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure sshd service is running on each container? `lsof -i tcp:22` or `netstat -l`

Comment: Yes, find it here:
`[root@c19af9926797 /]# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path

[root@c19af9926797 /]# lsof -i tcp:22
bash: lsof: command not found`

Comment: Well the connection is in being established. the SSL transaction seems to be failing. Try generating ssh keys `~# ssh-keygen`. Follow through the steps and try again.

Comment: It still fails... Does the SSH server have to own a RSA keypair to allow SSH connections?

Comment: I'm not sure. Sorry.